# batch file command to continue execution after calling a powershell script which is located outside

Tags: robocopy

Need one command, let me explain my query.
I am running a robocopy command using the .bat file

```
robocopy c:\Testing d:\Testing
```

After above command, I am calling powershell script by using below command.

```
powershell.exe -noexit -file .\Testreplace.ps1
```

Now, I wanted to continue the execution of remaining script in .bat file once the above powershell script is executed.

robocopy c:\test2 d:\test2

But it is not getting back to .bat script. Please give me any suggestion/command to continue execution.

--> My complete script:
       robocopy c:\Testing d:\Testing
       powershell.exe -noexit -file .\Testreplace.ps1
       robocopy c:\test2 d:\test2

Issue is, execution stopped at 2nd line only, not coming to 3rd line.
Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the (rather obvious) `-noexit` parameter to Powershell and it will actually exit after finishing to run `Testreplace.ps1`.